# How to list all (non-local) versions of an apt-get package?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

I'd like to find the oldest version of PyQt4 available to install via apt-get, and then install it.

I believe the package name is `python-qt4` and that I should install like so:

```
apt-get update
<FIND OLDEST VERSION SOMEHOW>
apt-get install python-qt4=VERSION
```

How can I search apt-get packages and list all versions, so that I cand find the oldest one?

Comment: `apt-get` will install the latest version suitable for 14.04

Comment: @sameerasy I am looking for the *oldest* version suitable for 14.04.

Comment: then just give `sudo apt-get install python-qt4` It'll find the best version possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-cache policy <packageName>` is what you are looking for. It lists all available package versions. 
The question was [asked on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340530/how-can-i-check-the-available-version-of-a-package-in-the-repositories) already.